# Floating action button blink after closing activity using Shared Element Transition

Tags: android, floating-action-button, shared-element-transition

I have an issue with Shared Element Transition.
When I return to MainActivity from DetailActivity, FAB blinking
[Gif example](https://media.giphy.com/media/1eulVWyQo3ZoEqDa0D/giphy.gif)

I used [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) sample project.
For shared element transition I made:

1. Enabled Window Content Transitions in styles.xml
   `<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>`
2. Assign a common transition name to the shared elements in both layouts. 
   `android:transitionName="image"`
3. Started the target activity by specifying a bundle of those shared elements and views from the source
   `holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Context context = v.getContext();
                   Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheeseDetailActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra(CheeseDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, holder.mBoundString);
                   MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
                   ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, new Pair<>(holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.avatar), "image"));
                   ActivityCompat.startActivity(context,intent, options.toBundle());
               }
           });`
   And when i press back button, FAB from detail Activity blinks in Main activity.
   I did not find a similar problem, so thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by hiding FAB before close Activity.
In `onBackPressed()` and in home button `onClick` i pasted:

```
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) myFab.getLayoutParams();
    params.setBehavior(null);
    myFab.requestLayout();
    myFab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: I really would like a more elegant solution, but your solution worked for me.